# Object must implement IConvertible?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sqldatasource, iconvertible

Getting this after solving a "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime" error. Using Vb.net/SQL Server 2000 updating a row via a gridview/sqldatasource:

Stored Procedure:

```
@ISTag varchar(10),
@PCISTag varchar(10),
@User varchar(50),
@Date_Start datetime,
@Date_End datetime,
@Status varchar(50),
@Cost money,
@Notes varchar(500),
@CreatedBy varchar(50),
@ModifiedBy varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC sp_changeLog 'HardDrive', @ISTag, @ModifiedBy

    UPDATE T_HardDrive
            SET PCIStag = @PCISTag,
            [User] = @User,
            Date_Start = @Date_Start,
            Date_End = @Date_End,
            [Status] = @Status,
            Cost = @Cost,
            Notes = @Notes,
            ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy
        WHERE ISTag = @ISTag
```

SQL Datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="InventoryHardDrive" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:InventoryConnectionString %>" 
                        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [T_HardDrive] WHERE [ISTag] = @original_ISTag" 
                        InsertCommand="sp_HardDriveInsert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
                        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
                        SelectCommand="sp_HardDriveSelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
                        UpdateCommand="sp_HardDriveUpdate" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <DeleteParameters>

                        </DeleteParameters>
                        <InsertParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ISTag" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="PCISTag" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="User" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Start" Type="DateTime" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Date_End" Type="DateTime" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CreatedBy" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedBy" Type="String" />
                        </InsertParameters>
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hideInactiveCheckBox" Name="Active" 
                                PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="filterText" DefaultValue="%" Name="ISTag" 
                                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ISTag" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="PCISTag" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="User" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Start" Type="DateTime" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Date_End" Type="DateTime" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CreatedBy" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedBy" Type="String" />
                        </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm setting the the Date_Start and Date_End parameters to the minimum date for now until I can figure out what is causing this.

```
Dim sqldatenull As SqlDateTime
sqldatenull = SqlDateTime.MinValue
e.NewValues("Date_Start") = sqldatenull
e.NewValues("Date_End") = sqldatenull
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i'd guess you need to convert to a sql date type and that it might work on later versions of sql server

Comment: DateTime is a type in 2000 so I don't think that's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a `DateTime` in the VB.NET code instead of a `SqlDateTime`.

Comment: Disabled the call to sp_changeLog, no change.

Comment: Changing to DateTime worked! You'd think SqlDateTime would be compatible? Odd indeed.

Comment: From the XML defn of the datasource it looks like it prefers a DateTime to a SqlDateTime. Yes, thats odd though.